# When a mail is sent from live mail with chinese content message body is displaying with some special charachers

Tags: php

I am using php mailer in my project. When I sent mail from live mail with chinese and Japanese content, message body is displaying as 
$BF;2DF;Hs>oF;!$L>2DL>Hs>oL>F;2DF;Hs>oF;!$L>2DL>Hs>oL>(B.

I'm unable to decode this. Which encoding technique it is and can we sent any parameter to live mail so that it can convert given chinese content to utf-8.

Comment: how are you preparing the headers when you call mail function?

Comment: Yep, more explicitly, did you set on your header `content-type` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the mail UTF-8 encoded, so set your headers to :

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

For subject encode it base64 :

```
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?='
```